# which model in R is suitable for my censored data, zero-inflated, hurdle, nada package or others

Tags: r, poisson

My data is like this:
1. There are a lot of zeros in it, so seems to be ok with poisson, zero-inflated or hurdle.
2. Almost al of my data are right-censored and left censored, so seems to be ok with NADA package or other similar packages for censored data.
3. Looks like the responsible variable follows negative binomial. The result looks ok when I use glm.nb.

Now, I want to take censored stuff into consideration. As far as I know, NADA, cesReg or other packages can deal with this. However, it looks like it just for the basic linear model like y=a+bx+c. But I hope my y can follow a negative binomial, poisson or others, so y=exp(a+bx+c), or even more complicated than this.

Is there someone who can tell me which package can do this: deal with censored data with more distribution?

Thanks

Comment: You can try `JAGS` and its `R` package `rjags` (or also `STAN` and `rstan`). It is not intended to deal specifically with your issue, but it allows to build a lot of models in the bayesian framework. It has a steep learning curve however, if you are not familiar with bayesian networks and techniques.

Comment: thanks a lot. let me take a look first